# Scrapy crawler doesn't work after the second run

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm generally new in scrapy so probably my issue is trivial but I totally don't know how to resolve my problem.

I wrote the crawler, which crawls the website to find nested URLs and finally returns the set of the URLs which was nested on the website.
I scraped a lot of pages by this crawler but now I have some troubles.

ISSUE DESCRIPTION:
When I run the spider for the first time I get the complete list of the URLs - and it's totally fine (a piece of the correct output):

```
2020-09-10 15:49:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-09-10 15:49:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-09-10 15:49:40 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-09-10 15:49:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ohpolly.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-09-10 15:49:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ohpolly.com/> (referer: None)
2020-09-10 15:49:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ohpolly.com/swim> (referer: https://www.ohpolly.com/)
2020-09-10 15:49:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ohpolly.com/dresses/maxi-dress> (referer: https://www.ohpolly.com/)
2020-09-10 15:49:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ohpolly.com/dresses/satin-dresses> (referer: https://www.ohpolly.com/)
2020-09-10 15:49:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ohpolly.com/dresses/midi-dresses> (referer: https://www.ohpolly.com/)
2020-09-10 15:49:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ohpolly.com/contacts> (referer: https://www.ohpolly.com/)
```

When I want to run the crawler for the second time almost after the first run, the crawler doesn't work and the output looks:

```
['url_checker.pipelines.UrlCheckerPipeline']
2020-09-10 16:29:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-09-10 16:29:55 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-09-10 16:29:55 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-09-10 16:29:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.ohpolly.com/> (referer: None)
2020-09-10 16:29:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-09-10 16:29:56 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 217,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 3083,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.386806,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 10, 14, 29, 56, 19532),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 58650624,
 'memusage/startup': 58650624,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 10, 14, 29, 55, 632726)}
2020-09-10 16:29:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

The crawler stops on the start-page. The settings of my crawler are the same in both cases:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Do I forget about some obvious setting which I should pass to the crawler? I try to use a different user agent but it doesn't help.

Do you have any ideas about what I should do to deal with this issue?

Comment: There are many possible reasons for that, like getting different versions from an AB test. Your best option is to log the response body when the spider could not find the links and check it closely.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help;) I checked the logs and the website thinks that the crawler is a robot, so I must find the solution to this issue!